# Install EKS with Fargate using CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, aws-fargate

I'm able to create an EKS cluster using Cloudformation. I'm also able to have a "node group" and EC2's + autoscaling. On the other side I can also install a FargateProfile and create "fargate nodes". This works well. But I want to use only fargate (no EC2 nodes etc). Here for I need to host my management pods (in kube-system) also on Fargate. How can I managed this?

I tried this:

```
Resources:
  FargateProfile:
    Type: AWS::EKS::FargateProfile
    Properties:
      ClusterName: eks-test-cluster-001
      FargateProfileName: fargate
      PodExecutionRoleArn: !Sub 'arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/AmazonEKSFargatePodExecutionRole'
      Selectors:
        - Namespace: kube-system
        - Namespace: default
        - Namespace: xxx
      Subnets:
        !Ref Subnets
```

But my management pods remain on the EC2's. Probably I'm missing some labels but is this the way to go? Some labels are generated with a hash so I can't just add them in my fargateProfile.

with eksctl it seems possible: Adding the --fargate option in the command above creates a cluster without a node group. However, eksctl creates a pod execution role, a Fargate profile for the default and kube-system namespaces, and it patches the coredns deployment so that it can run on Fargate.

but how to do this in CloudFormation?

I also tried with the labels but then I got an error in CloudFormation: Model `validation failed (#: extraneous key [k8s-app] is not permitted)`

Answer (score 0):

I am not duplicating this template.
But since I had similar issue to the model validation failed, if your using labels, make sure you have format of Key: XXX
Value: XXX

Answer (score 0):

The below configuration works for me but after manually patching the core DNS deployment file. Any idea of how to run the core DNS on the Fargate with cloud formation.

```
Resources:
  FargateProfile:
    Type: 'AWS::EKS::FargateProfile'
    DependsOn: ControlPlane
    Properties:
      ClusterName: my-cluster
      FargateProfileName: fp-default
      PodExecutionRoleArn: !GetAtt 
        - FargatePodExecutionRole
        - Arn
      Selectors:
        - Namespace: default
        - Namespace: kube-system
          Labels:
            - Key: k8s-app
              Value: kube-dns
```

Answer (score 0):

The CloudFormation template is correct. You need change the annotation of CoreDNS deployment - remove the annotation:

```
Annotations: eks.amazonaws.com/compute-type: ec2
```

For it use this command:

```
kubectl patch deployment coredns \
    -n kube-system \
    --type json \
    -p='[{"op": "remove", "path": "/spec/template/metadata/annotations/eks.amazonaws.com~1compute-type"}]'
```

Doc ref.: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/fargate-getting-started.html